# Dynamically Supplying Metadata for Social Preview Cards

Tags: javascript, twitter, twitter-card

I am currently working on a custom URL shortener and am trying to figure out how to "inject" my own social preview metadata dynamically for each page. (eg. for Twitter Cards) I had originally planned on doing this in much the same way as I am with the actual redirect, fetching the data using the JavaScript fetch API. After reading a little more though it does not appear that this approach will work [since it doesn't look like the twitter (and other social media web crawlers) run JS when looking for the metadata.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35882222/does-twitters-url-crawler-execute-javascript)

Is this correct?

If so, is there a way I can load the metadata from a dynamic source instead of just having to create a new html file for every redirect?

It looks like I can probably do something, at least for the image based on a test of [this link](https://xenodochial-newton-ab9a71.netlify.app/) (using https://source.unsplash.com/random for the image) through [the twitter card validator](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator). But what would be the best approach to doing something similar? Everything I can think of would use JS.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar pages in production.

You'll need to use a server-side language (like PHP, or node.js) to set the meta tags for your twitter cards, and use javascript to redirect the page.